# How can I program a JavaScript and HTML web page in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have seen videos where people have made web projects in Visual Studio without using visual c++ or visual basic. (like [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/visual-studio/visual-studio-2012-javascript-editor)) All I want is to make a simple html and javascript webpage using Visual Studio's programming features, while keeping it contained in a solution. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, you simply go to file>add>existing web site, (I already had a folder with some code) and you're done. Sorry for inconveniencing anyone.